# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header...Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access". Local server not working as solution?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a small app to create an animated overlay. It's supposed to pull text from local txt/xml files and update the html accordingly. According to various other answers that I've researched, the solution was to create a local server, which I did using pythons SimpleHTTPServer. However I'm still having the same issue.

For instance, I originally had

```
$.get("info/player1.txt", function(data) {
        p1new = data;
    });
```

which I replaced with

```
$.get("http://localhost:8000/info/player1.txt", function(data) {
    p1new = data;
});
```

but this produces the access error. Completely stumped. This is purely html/css/jquery on a local web server.

Comment: This happens if you are on https and you try to go to http with ajax. Can you make sure you are not doing this?

Comment: I don't believe so. How would I check?

Comment: Just check connection type you are connected to when you try to request data via ajax. Are you on HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 Definitely not HTTPS

Comment: Possible relevant post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome